# When i create a UIBarButtonItem using initWithTitle,it does not respond to touch inside the title,only outside the title can be respond

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

here is the code

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Interpretations" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showInterpretations:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

in my program,when i create a button and set it's title,the default value of `titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled` is `YES`,this cause the same problem,so I must set `UserInteractionEnabled` to `NO` so that the button can responding correctly.

but in a navigationBar,the class of `UIBarButtonItem` is not `UIView`,i try to create `UIBarButtonItem` using `initWithImage` and it works well,i think when using `initWithTitle` there must be a titleLabel whose `userInteractionEnabled` is YES. I still want to know how it occur and what to do to fix it,thanks.

Comment: there is no property of userInteractionEnabled for UIBarButtonItem. see the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: firstly, you need not set a `UIButton` object's `titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` (because... by default it is **`NO`** anyways). secondly... what's the problem? does the `UIBarButtonItem` not work?

Comment: but when I NSLog,the default value is YES,that means when touching in the titleLabel,the button won't respond. Touches between button'bound and titleLabel'bound can respond.Though I can change the value to NO,but in my searchbar,the cancel button has the same problem

Comment: I guess something wrong but I can't find the reason.However,fix the button and barButtonItem problem is easy,I really have no idea with the cancel button problem in search bar. At least,I know they have the same problem because I do many tests.

Answer (score 0):

i use this and it works :D..hope it helped you :)

```
UIButton* backToRecent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backToRecent setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navB_V.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backToRecent setTitle:@"button title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[backToRecent addTarget:self action:@selector(deselect) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backToRecent setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 30)];
[backToRecent setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -30, 0, -30)];
UIBarButtonItem* navItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backToRecent];

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:navItem];
```

Comment: in my program,there is a search bar whose cancel button having the same problem

Comment: i don;t understand what you are saying to me.. you can use this for every button in navigationbar

Comment: in searchbar ,the cancel button is create by system,the code is like self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchBar

Comment: i don't know this..sorry

Comment: it works by using initWithCustomView,but using initWithTitle causes the problem. Badly,there is no API for create a new cancel button in a seachbar

Comment: when I build a new program ,these buttons work well,only in the current program they can't work correctly,that's so weird